# Python vs C++ Tensorflow inferencing

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, benchmarking, inference

Is it really worth it to implement a C++ code for loading an already trained model and then fetch it instead of using Python?.

I was wondering this because as far as I understand, Tensorflow for python is C++ behind the scenes (as it is for numpy). So if one ends up basically having a Python program fetching the model loaded with a Python module it would perform pretty similar than using a module in C++ right?

Is there any benchmark? I wasn't able to find anything supporting this theory.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same question.

Comment: No sorry, I did not find anything clear. My opinion is that the performance should be rather similar as tensorflow is using compiled code from c++. Do not have this opinion as a reference though. I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Write in the language that you are familiar with, in a way that you can maintain.

If it takes you a day longer to write it in the "faster" language, but only saves a minute of runtime, then it'll have to run 24*60 times to have caught up, and multiple times more than that to have been economical.

Comment: The thing is that right now in Python is fetching at 4ms per sample, if I could get <2ms with C++ would be worth it to remember how to use C++. In my case the fetching will be done over millions of samples. The question is to know if there is a real advantage of inferencing a Tensorflow model with C++ instead of Python.